# Why do Swift operator overloads need to be type methods?

Tags: swift, static, operator-overloading, operators

[The Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID42) shows that operator methods like the following must be written as `static`:

```
struct Vector2D {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
}

extension Vector2D {
    static func + (left: Vector2D, right: Vector2D) -> Vector2D {
        return Vector2D(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
    }
}

let vector = Vector2D(x: 3.0, y: 1.0)
let anotherVector = Vector2D(x: 2.0, y: 4.0)
let combinedVector = vector + anotherVector
```

If you remove the `static` keyword, it will cause a compile error:

> Operator '+' declared in extension of 'Vector2D' must be 'static'

What is the reason for this requirement? Why can't we write this as a non-static method?

I could blindly accept that "this is just the way it's done". But I'd like to understand why this is necessary, so that I might understand the Swift language better. I have not been able to find a specific reason for this requirement.

If I had to guess, I'd guess that the default operators in Swift are implemented as type methods, and so our custom operators must likewise be static. But this is pure speculation.

Comment: I don't have a full answer but if it was an instance then you would need one instance to add two other instances or it had to be mutating which is also a bit strange for a basic addition. `vector1.+(vector2)`...

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585)

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for chiming in. I edited my question slightly to make it a little more clear about what I'm after here. I'm not asking, "Why is the language designed this way?" Because I don't know if this is a language design choice. If that turns out to be the answer, that's fine. What I'm really wondering is if there is some rule within the language itself that I am overlooking which might explain the reason for this requirement. Or some logic behind how Swift works which necessitates this requirement.

Comment: These are some great answers! In summary, it sounds like this is a language design choice, and the reason for this choice is because "it works better that way". The answers below demonstrate a variety of benefits from doing it as a type method rather than an instance method. As the posters said, this way the code can be written simpler and cleaner, the language has _symmetry_, and this sort of operator behavior more naturally belongs to the type rather than an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense to me. A binary operator takes 2 objects as parameters, and returns a result.

Such an operator does not belong to an instance of any object. It is a static method on the class. For your example of the `+` method for the `Vector2D` type, it is a method that knows how to add 2 `Vector2D` objects together.

You don't call the `+` method on an instance of `Vector2D`. You say "Hey, `Vector2D` type, how do I add together two instances of your type?.

You are "talking to" the class, not an instance of the class.

### Edit:

If it was an instance method, you'd have to express an add operator as a message to one of the operands:

```
extension Vector2D {
    func addVector(_: Vector2D) -> Vector2D {
        // Code to sum two vectors
    }
}
```

And you'd call it as

```
sum = aVector.addVector(anotherVector)
```

Comment: To me, this answer seems to be the most compelling reason for requiring that operator overloads are written as type methods: because that's the most natural way to reason about and use the language, when it comes to operators. The other answers raise further good points. Sweeper reinforces this answer as well as showing that it could have been done differently. The "official" answer seems to be what Kiril S. mentioned, simply that "this is a language design choice". He also mentions the importance of symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Operators don't have to be static. They can also be global functions.

```
struct Vector2D {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
}

func + (left: Vector2D, right: Vector2D) -> Vector2D {
    return Vector2D(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

let vector = Vector2D(x: 3.0, y: 1.0)
let anotherVector = Vector2D(x: 2.0, y: 4.0)
let combinedVector = vector + anotherVector
```

And if you are asking why they can't be *instance* methods, well, because instance methods need an extra instance of `Vector2D` to be invoked. That instance, plus the two parameters that `+` needs, means that you need 3 `Vector2D`s to call `+`, which doesn't make much sense...

On the other hand, operators could have been designed like this:

```
extension Vector2D {
    func +(right: Vector2D) -> Vector2D { ... }
}
```

where instead of operating on two parameters, binary operators operate on `self` and a single parameter. This is similar to how Kotlin's operator overloading is designed.

As far as I can see, there's nothing in Swift that prevents Swift from being designed like this. The reason for this is most likely aesthetics, such as "having 2 parameters makes more sense", as Duncan C suggested, and having 2 parameters is also clearer which one is the left operand and which one is the right operand.

Answer (score 1):

This is a language design choice, and different languages decided on opposites: C++ won't allow static operators, while C# requires them to be static, just like Swift.

To me the most compelling reason to have operators static is a *symmetry*.

Lets for a moment replace `+` with function called `plus`. If `plus` is static, you'd call it as `Vector2D.plus(vector, anotherVector)`, which will be the same as calling `Vector2D.plus(anotherVector, vector)`.

If it was an instance member, you'd call it as `vector.plus(anotherVector)`, which may or may not be the same as `anotherVector.plus(vector)`. I.e. if `vector` is `nil`, the `vector.plus(anotherVector)` will definitely be `nil`, while `anotherVector.plus(vector)` will be equal to `anotherVector`.

Similarly, the operator `+` being static allows that `vector + anotherVector == anotherVector + vector`, regardless of `nil` status of both vectors.